# Open folder in Command Prompt and path of current folder

Tags: node.js, windows, path, windows-10, directory

When I click «Open in Command Prompt» in Visual Studio Code selected folder (C:\playground\ng2\app) should open in command line. But in command prompt display path C:\
[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0mNh.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the [AutoRun](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433) setting for cmd.exe to `cd \`?

Comment: Yes, value data is cd\

Comment: I have installed new value cd.\ and it has earned. Did I do the right thing? Thank you!